# What do water-carriers have to do with Parshat Emor?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Many cities in Eastern Europe used to have a Kiddush for Parshat Emor sponsored by the water-carrier's guild. (This much is true, and the real reason makes for an OK entry in the Pun-im Chalashos) What is the connection between water-carriers and Emor?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: [The real reason.](//books.google.com/books?id=2mKoQoillNkC&pg=PT17&dq=emor)

Answer (score 1):

Parshas Emor teaches us that our freedom is kabbalistically contingent upon the labor of the water carriers. This is obvious as the numerical value of parshas emor (פרשת אמר) is 1221 which is equivalent to הוא יהיה לי עבד ואתם עלו לשלום אל אביכם (Gen 44:17) "He shall be to me a worker and you shall go free..." The water carriers remind us of this annually every parshas emor by sponsoring the kiddush.